# Azure resource provider registration failure for "Microsoft.Web"

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

From terraform I am trying to create Azure function app. It was working till last week. Now I am trying to deploy to a new Subscription. In that subscription none of the resource providers were registered. So terraform tries to register during "terraform apply". Fails with below step

```
│ Original Error: Cannot register providers: Microsoft.Web. Errors were: waiting for Subscription Provider (Subscription: "xxxxxx"
│ Provider Name: "Microsoft.Web") to be registered: context deadline exceeded
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on providers.tf line 18, in provider "azurerm":
│   18: provider "azurerm" {
│ 
╵
```

I also tried to add 'skip_provider_registration' and manually tried with AZ cli command. It fails for 'Microsoft.web'.

```
az provider register --namespace "Microsoft.Web"
```

In portal, it stays with 'Registering' status for couple of hours.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you checked the registration status with `az provider show --namespace "Microsoft.Web"` command. @Aram

Comment: Yes, but its dumping 5k lines json. Does it contain any detail?

Comment: If it is success, it will give the detailed output with all the available api versions. @Aram

Answer (score 1):

According to these [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1048633/resource-provider-stuck-on-registering-or-unregist) and [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26801) discussions, it is an ongoing issue which is happening frequently with the provider registrations when moving to another tenant or subscription. And it is a very transient issue which should go away after some time period.

***Need to check below:***

Before registering a provider check that you have necessary permissions.

> You must have permission to do the `/register/action` operation for the resource provider. The permission is included in the Contributor and Owner roles as detailed in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#register-resource-provider).

And also try passing [`--debug/--verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/provider?view=azure-cli-latest#az-provider-register-optional-parameters) parameters along with the `az provider register` command while registering to retrieve more detailed information on the error part if it fails continuously.

As you mentioned, you can also go with the `skip_provider_registration = true` when you are facing this registration kind of errors. But make sure that the providers are to be registered before you are using below field in your code.

```
provider "azurerm" { 
skip_provider_registration = true 
}
```

I tried to register the `"Microsoft.Web"` namespace in my `AzCLI` environment and was good to proceed without any conflicts.

```bash
az provider register --namespace "Microsoft.Web"
```

[image]

Check the registration status by using below `CLI` command which gives output as shown below.

```bash
 az provider show --namespace "Microsoft.Web"
```

[image]

If still the issue persists with `CLI`, try using `PowerShell` command to register the provider.

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Web"
```

*Note: If still the issue persists, raise a support request with the Azure CLI team as it might help to resolve the issue quickly.*

Comment: Looks like it is related to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1373477/azure-resource-provider-microsoft-web-taking-more?page=1&orderby=Helpful#answers I have added my comment as well. But many are reporting the same issue with Microsoft.web

Comment: The same issue is happening when you are moving it into other subscription. They are looking into the issue for now. @Aram

Comment: Yes, Just now MSFT responded saying it is fixed. But is there any known workaround for this?

Comment: For time being, you can prefer other workarounds using bicep or any ARM template to create a function app. Is that works for you? @Aram

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when completed via Azure Portal
Subscriptions -> resource provider-> search and register e.g. Microsoft.Web